# How to use ngFor with two variables?

Tags: angular

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ng-containte *ngFor="let item of array"; let j = item>

<ng-containte *ngFor="let item of array"; let i = index>

<input (ngModelChange) = "fun(value,2,item)" >
```

with following javascript:

```
fun(value:string, index:number, item:number){
 do something...
}
```

How to use one ngFor to control "i" and "j" 
so that it won't loop 2 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use nested `ng-container`:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of array"; let j = index>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of array"; let i = index>
    <input (ngModelChange) = "fun(value,i,j)" >
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

If you really want to use `item` and it's not a typo in your post, no need for a duplication:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of array">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item2 of array"; let i = index>
    <input (ngModelChange) = "fun(value,i,item)" >
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```